# Change Content-Type header for java SOAP Client

Tags: java, http-headers, webservice-client

I have to set the Content-Type header for client request to `Text/xml`, by default it is `Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8`

I am setting the header via

```
   HashMap headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

   headers.put("X-Client-Version", Collections.singletonList("1.0-RC"));
   headers.put("Content-type", Collections.singletonList("Text/xml;"));

   ((BindingProvider) h).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext
   .HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```

The `X-Client-Version` header is successfully set but `Content-Type` remains with it's default value of `text/xml; charset=utf-8`

How can i change the content type header ?

Comment: May be `"Text/xml"` is wrong and you need to use `"text/xml"` (with lower-case).

Comment: It needs to be set to `Text/xml`, i have tried `text/xml` as well but it does not change from it's default `text/xml; charset=utf-8`